No response when using share play to share screen and remote control
When two iPhones are using FaceTime, if one iPhone sends a request for “ask for share”, the other iPhone will not receive the request. Screen sharing can only be successful when one phone "share my screen". But even so, after successfully sharing the screen, when clicking the "remote control" button, neither phone responds.
I have made sure that both iPhone are iOS 18 beta version, facetime app are latest version and network is stable.
